# Normal form(s) for the elements of hyperbolic triangle groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometry

I'm seeking a reference or a sketch for any sort of normal form that would enable rapid enumeration without redundancies of the elements of hyperbolic triangle groups and/or von Dyck groups.

Comment: might be here: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1465327

Comment: @Ian: It is a very interesting paper. But doesn't it follow from the thesis I cited? That would be remarkable because the paper is very non-elementary (comparing to the thesis). Perhaps the main difference is that the thesis gives non-geodesic normal forms while the paper gives geodesic normal forms? Anyway, thanks for the reference. 

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gerhard.Hiss/Students/DiplomarbeitPfeiffer.pdf) thesis contains a complete rewriting system for every triangle group (see Section C at the end of the thesis). Then normal forms are just words that do not contain left parts of the rewriting rules (which is just a finite set of words). This gives enumeration of all elements without redundancies.

Comment: I believe the rewriting system for the $(p,q,r)$-triangle group in Appendix C assumes that $p \geq q \geq r \geq 6$.

Answer (score 3):

The general reference for this topic is "Word processing in groups", Epstein et. al., MR1161694 (93i:20036). Your groups all have automatic structures, and that book gives an enumeration method as you ask for, which applies to any automatic structure on a group.